# 2013 Workflow History List

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

Is it possible to create a custom list which is then to be used as a workflow history list in a ShPD2013 workflow?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure.  But I'm pretty sure you can choose to set up a new workflow history list when you create a new workflow on a list.  Perhaps that would serve what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can change the tasklist in sharepoint designer. On the workflow settings page, you have the option of creating a new tasklist under workflow tasklist dropdown control. Select and click on new, name the list and tham that list will be used as a task list for the workflow

[For Reference](https://blogs.perficient.com/2009/09/03/designer-workflow-task-list-association-no-more-pain-my-friend/)